# Quartz Cron Misfire

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler, scheduler, misfire-instruction

I am new Quartz scheduler and having some trouble.

When I use simple Scheduler as follows:

```
Trigger misFiredTriggerB = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().startAt(DateUtils.addSeconds(new Date(), -63)).withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withMisfireHandlingInstructionFireNow()).build();
```

it works fine, considers the misfire threshold and misfire instruction depending on case.

However when I use cron scheduler and use the time few seconds before the current time, it neither consider threshold nor the misfire instruction.

```
Trigger misFiredTriggerA =  TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("SimpleTrigger").withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("30,35,38 50 17 * * ?").withMisfireHandlingInstructionFireAndProceed()).build();
```

Is there anything that I am doing wrong with cron?

Another question is how can I easily change the misfire threshold value in eclipse cause by default it is set to 60000?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between Simple and Cron triggers.

- **Simple Trigger** execution is scheduled for exact date that can be before or after now. In your case it is more than 60 seconds (property *org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold* (in milliseconds)) before now, so Quartz assumes such trigger as misfired.
- Quartz uses **Cron Trigger** to schedule execution for the nearest date in future that respects cron expression. So in your case job will be triggered tomorrow at 17:50:30